# Change the footer in a word document with VBA code / Macro

Tags: vba, footer, word-2010

How can I change the footer information in a word document with VBA?

When the document is loaded, the VBA code will get the necessary info from a database, and I want to attach that info to the footer.

I got the fetching the info from the DB down, but attaching it to the footer is another story.

Any simple related examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will create a header and footer on every page.

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header goes here"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer goes here"
End With
```

You can find more information on how to use headers and footers with vba here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221968%28v=office.11%29.aspx